# how to take averaged diurnal for each month for two columns with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, multiple-columns, mean

I have a time series data of two columns, and I want a graph with averaged hourly pattern for each month, like the graph attached but with two time series.

```
             timestamp ET_control ET_treatment    
1  2016-01-01 00:00:00         NA           NA  
2  2016-01-01 00:30:00         NA           NA  
3  2016-01-01 01:00:00         NA           NA  
4  2016-01-01 01:30:00         NA           NA  
5  2016-01-01 02:00:00         NA           NA  
6  2016-01-01 02:30:00         NA           NA  
7  2016-01-01 03:00:00         NA           NA  
8  2016-01-01 03:30:00         NA           NA  
9  2016-01-01 04:00:00         NA           NA  
10 2016-01-01 04:30:00         NA           NA  
11 2016-01-01 05:00:00         NA           NA  
12 2016-01-01 05:30:00         NA           NA  
13 2016-01-01 06:00:00         NA           NA  
14 2016-01-01 06:30:00         NA           NA  
15 2016-01-01 07:00:00         NA           NA  
16 2016-01-01 07:30:00         NA           NA  
17 2016-01-01 08:00:00         NA           NA  
18 2016-01-01 08:30:00         NA           NA  
19 2016-01-01 09:00:00         NA           NA  
20 2016-01-01 09:30:00         NA           NA  
21 2016-01-01 10:00:00         NA           NA  
22 2016-01-01 10:30:00         NA           NA  
23 2016-01-01 11:00:00         NA           NA  
24 2016-01-01 11:30:00 0.09863437           NA  
25 2016-01-01 12:00:00 0.11465258           NA  
26 2016-01-01 12:30:00 0.12356855           NA  
27 2016-01-01 13:00:00 0.09246215  0.085398782  
28 2016-01-01 13:30:00 0.08843156  0.072877001  
29 2016-01-01 14:00:00 0.08536019  0.081885947  
30 2016-01-01 14:30:00 0.08558541           NA  
31 2016-01-01 15:00:00 0.05571436           NA  
32 2016-01-01 15:30:00 0.04087248  0.038582547  
33 2016-01-01 16:00:00 0.04233724           NA  
34 2016-01-01 16:30:00 0.02150660  0.019560578  
35 2016-01-01 17:00:00 0.01803765  0.019691155  
36 2016-01-01 17:30:00         NA  0.005190489  
37 2016-01-01 18:00:00         NA           NA  
38 2016-01-01 18:30:00         NA           NA  
39 2016-01-01 19:00:00         NA           NA  
40 2016-01-01 19:30:00         NA           NA  
41 2016-01-01 20:00:00         NA           NA  
42 2016-01-01 20:30:00         NA           NA  
43 2016-01-01 21:00:00         NA           NA  
44 2016-01-01 21:30:00         NA           NA  
45 2016-01-01 22:00:00         NA           NA  
46 2016-01-01 22:30:00         NA           NA  
47 2016-01-01 23:00:00         NA           NA  
48 2016-01-01 23:30:00         NA           NA  
49 2016-01-02 00:00:00         NA           NA  
50 2016-01-02 00:30:00         NA           NA
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given t is your data.frame with packages dplyr and ggplot2:

```
t <- t %>% mutate(
       month = format(strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%b"),
       hour=format(strptime(timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%H"))

tm <- t %>% group_by(month, hour) %>% 
       summarize(ET_control_mean=mean(ET_control, na.rm=T))

ggplot(tm, aes(x=hour, y=ET_control_mean)) + geom_point() + facet_wrap(~ month)
```

if you want to have both columns in your graph, you should transform your data into the 'long' format.

Comment: Thank you so much, this code is really saved me. (a small typo is at the end of second least line  rm.na should be na.rm)